# Freeze downstream parameters but allow gradient propagate back for training upstream parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

Suppose I have a neural network with parameters `a` and `b`.

```
class MyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)
        self.b = torch.tensor(-1.0, requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.a * x + self.b

# The "upstream" model to be trained
model1 = MyNetwork()
# The "downstream" model which is just an alias for model1
# Its parameter should be frozen but allow gradient flow through
model2 = model1
```

Let's apply the same network twice [image: y=a(ax+b)+b].

```
input = 2.0
x1 = model1(input)
x2 = model2(x1)
target = 1.0
loss = (target - x2) ** 2
```

Normally, the gradient for parameter `a` is
[image].

The first part [image: first] is the gradient for `model1` and the second part [image: second] is for `model2`.

Now I need to treat `model2`'s parameters as constants and train only `model1`. In the sense that applying only first part of gradients to `a`. i.e.
[image: tilde].

I need to update `a` with that gradient
[image: sgd].

I cannot use `torch.no_grad()` which will stop gradient flowing to `model1`.

I cannot set `torch.optim.Adam`'s `params` to be only those of `model1` because `model1` and `model2` are the same.

I can get [image: dl_dx1] [by registering hooks](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-i-see-grad-of-an-intermediate-variable/94/7) but have no idea on getting [image: dx1_da].

In case of applying the same model multiple rounds, say I want gradients for [image: xk] if `k` is not a prime number, how to code this up in PyTorch in a general way for (maybe) large neural networks? Can TensorFlow or other frameworks do this easily?